# How to group by one column and summation of second?

Tags: t-sql

tsql newbie here.

I have a table, similar to this one:

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
CarId    CarName    UserId    RentedTimes    CrashedTimes
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
1        Ferrari     1         2              0
2        DB9         1         5              0
3        Ferrari     2         4              0
4        Audi        3         1              0
5        Audi        1         1              0
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Assuming the table is called 'Cars', I am trying to select total number of times each of cars were rented. According to the table above, Ferrari was rented total of 6 times, DB9 five times and Audi twice.

I tried doing this:

```
select CarName, SUM(RentedTimes)
from Cars
group by CarName, RentedTimes
order by RentedTimes desc
```

but, it is returning two rows of ferrari with 2,4 as rented times and so on..

How do I select all cars, and total times each were rented, please?

Thanks

---

Edited the query to include sort order, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select CarName, SUM(RentedTimes)
from Cars
group by CarName
ORDER BY SUM(RentedTimes) DESC
```

Try this way.. removed  RentedTimes from group by

Comment: wow.. I thought, if I don't include RentedTimes in groub by clause, it would complain that it's not included... why does it work?

Comment: aaa, I tried to order by RentedTimes desc, and it did complain.. that's why I added it there... thanks

Comment: so How do I retain the sort order now, please?

Comment: ORDER BY SUM(RentedTimes) DESC